# what is the difference between "constexpr" and "static constexpr" variables of the non-class type in a header file?

Tags: c++11, static, header-files, constexpr

I have a header file `test.hxx` which will be included in multiple translation units. The header file is as below:

```
namespace program_exec
{
static constexpr int DEFAULT_VAL = 0;

static constexpr char *name = "proc_exec";
}
```

I have included this header file in multiple translation units (*.cxx) and it works fine.

But removing the static infront of `constexpr char*` causes a linking error i.e, if I change the `static constexpr char *name = "proc_exec"` to `constexpr char *name = "proc_exec";`

I am getting a linker error saying that

> ```
> error: multiple definition of program_exec::name
> ```

But making the same change for integers works fine i.e, changing `static constexpr int = DEFAULT_VALUE;` to `constexpr int = DEFAULT_VALUE;`.

Does difference does removing the `static**` infront `constexpr int` and `constexpr char*` makes?

Please help me in understanding the difference. Thank you very much in advance.

[Edit]

Having a variable as a "**static constexpr**" in a header file and using this header file in multiple translation units. Does each translation unit has its own copy of the variable (or) does the compiler keeps only one copy by optimizing it?

Because using a static variable in a header file with the namespace scope has internal linkage and any translation unit which includes this header file has its own copy of the variable.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Which compiler and which version? This behavior would be expected if you had a `#define constexpr const` somewhere, but otherwise it would be indicative of a compiler bug.

Comment: I am using a clang for cross compilation with version 3.8.

Comment: And you didn't get any warnings from the compiler with `static constexpr char *name = "proc_exec";`? (In particular, you should be getting a `-Wwritable-strings`.)

Comment: Atleast I didn't see any warnings from the compiler. I think a **constexpr** variable has a internal linkage right. So we add it to the header file. Does all the translation units which use this header file will have its own copy right? In this case, why do we get a compilation error?

Comment: I strongly suspect that you have a `#define` somewhere. Try `#undef constexpr` and see what happens.

Comment: I have enabled all the warnings and checked again. I am getting the below warning "**warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *const'
      [-Wwritable-strings]**". Can you tell me what does it suggests?

Comment: OK, and you still get the multiple definition error?

Comment: No I am not getting the error now. But it doesn't make sense. I got the error previously.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the _multiple definition_ error with gcc when removing those `static`s.

Comment: I downvoted as you cannot reproduve your problem.

Comment: Maybe too obvious but, do you have a multiple inclusion guard?